# Setting Aspect Ratio of SVGs

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have numerous `.svg` logos from popular brands to use in an image carousel. My problem is the images are different sizes and the brands end up displaying like so ...

[image]

The Argos image is much smaller than the Apple, and Epic, logo. Ideally I'd like them all to be the same aspect ratio so they fit well together.

How can I do this with CSS, or JavaScript?

Comment: how are you setting them to `50%` ?

Comment: you may want to calculate a common aspect-ratio and then scale accordingly - either to equal height or equal width. see https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratios-svg and https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg

Comment: Edited question for clarity. Unhold.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `max-width` of the elements to a certain pixel size.

```
.svg {
   max-width: 125px;
}
```

If you use percentages(50%), a svg that has 400px width will have 200px and one that has 1000px will have 500px, so that approach will not work.

In the above example I used a `.svg` class to target them but you can use simply `svg`, or put them in a div with a desired class name.